# how to "fix" container element height when scrollbar shows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal scrollbar which will only show when hover. But the problem is when it shows, it will increase the height of it's container and push the following elements down.
[the demo examle](http://jsfiddle.net/xff1874/PWbAL/3/).you can see the **two** div will be pushed down when the scrollbar shows

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="one">
    <div class="oneChild">the height is unknown,the height is unknown,the height is unknown,the height is unknown</div>
</div>
<div class="two">I'm two</div>
```

There are are some rules:

1. The wrapper and one height can't be fixed,because the **oneChild ** content height is unkonwn.And the height of both are all decided by their children.
2. The scroball only show when hover.you can use js or css to control it's visible.
3. Any js/css solution will be welcome.

Comment: Is it ok to disable the horizontal scrollbar? http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/PWbAL/1/

Comment: @Andrew the scrollbar can't be disable.

Answer (score 2):

If jquery is an option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    height = $('.one').height();
    $('.two').css('marginTop', height + 'px');
});
```

css:

```
.one {
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px seagreen solid;
     position:relative;
 }
 .one:hover {
     overflow: scroll;
 }
 .two {
     position: absolute;
     top:30px;
 }
```

Comment: because the oneChild content is unkown.so use the position:absoulte and top abou two will be fixed,but the two actually is static.I do some update about the demo.tks.

Answer (score 0):

If the child of one will never change, then you could get the height of the element after a height has been set, and then fix it at that height.

```
var $one = $('.one');
var height = $one.height();

$one.css('height', height);
```

If the height of the child of one may change, you could fix the height when you are hovering over the element, and set it to auto when you stop hovering.

```
var $one = $('.one');
var height = $one.height();

$one.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $one.css('height', height);
});

$one.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $one.css('height', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the div on hover to the height when the scrollbar isn't there.  Assuming that jQuery is ok:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oneHeight = $('.one').height();
    $('.one').hover(
         function(){ $(this).height(oneHeight); },
         function(){ $(this).height(oneHeight); }
    );
});
```

This does add an unfortunate vertical scrollbar, but if you want the vertical position to stay the same, you need to have the vertical bar to see the content that the horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:add padding-bottom first ,it is as high as horizontal scroball,then when mouseover event happen,padding-bottom set zero.